# Возможность динамической задачи переменной

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно пройти по списку и каждому name задать value, непосредственно не указывая название переменной, а забирая её из списка. Как бы не пробовал - просто видимо недостаточно знаний в данном деле

```js
      for(i=0;i<info.length;i++) {
        
        //info[i].name = info[i].value
      }
```

[image: Список]

Comment: Почему не просто info.length ? Там массив же

Comment: Сам уже немного запутался :/ Подправил

Comment: ну я бы попробовал для начала для перебора элементов массива foreach... или в чем проблема, не пойму.... недостаточно исходных условий задачи видимо, не понимаю что вы хотите сделать

Comment: и закомментировано. там внутри ничего не делается. так долго гадать будем

Comment: Перебрать все объекты, взять name, сделать из неё переменную, задать ей значение value.
Как пример:
warn_2 = '718848404377042985'

Comment: Ну сделать переменную не получится, потому что переменной нужно имя писать руками. Можно сделать только глобальную переменную в объекте global. Или просто локальный объект с ключами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант создания объекта с ключами, который можно использовать локально как переменные:

```
let vars = {};

info.forEach( item => {
    vars[ item.name ] = item.value;
});

console.log( vars.warn_2 );
```

Просто создать локальную переменную без знания её имени (динамически) нельзя. Можно только глобальные, потому что тогда это ключи объекта global в ноде или window в браузере.

Comment: Благодарю, очень сильно помогли :)